# gem environment and $GEM_PATH not updating when using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to upgrade ruby and rails gem on a server with cPanel, to do this I installed rvm and I successfully installed different versions of ruby... great stuff!

Having a problem though, the server seems to be ignoring which gemset to use. After installing a fresh copy of 1.9.2 I still get the same list of gems, and the GEM_PATH/GEMHOME is the same:

```
$>gem env

RubyGems Environment:
– RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
– RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
– INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ruby/ruby/gems
– RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
– EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ruby/ruby/gems/bin
– RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
– ruby
– x86_64-linux
– GEM PATHS:
– /home/ruby/ruby/gems
– GEM CONFIGURATION:
– :update_sources => true
– :verbose => true
– :benchmark => false
– :backtrace => false
– :bulk_threshold => 1000
– “gem” => “–remote –gen-rdoc –run-tests”
– “gemhome” => “/home/ruby/ruby/gems”
– “gempath” => []
– “rdoc” => “–inline-source –line-numbers”
– REMOTE SOURCES:
– http://rubygems.org/
```

Creating new gemsets and trying to use the new gemset doesn't change anything

Would love to get this working, an ideas what I could do to solve this?

P.S: I understand this will break the "ruby on rails" feature of cPanel and users will have to use the shell prompt to generate an app.

```
~]# rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p357 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: Should this be moved to stackoverflow?

Comment: check to make sure 1.9.2-p290 is default ruby with rvm list ! and also make sure you don't have .rvmrc from previous installation !

Comment: No previous installation to speak of

Comment: can you put output of rvm list command and rvm version

Comment: Edited answer to include rvm-list output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you specify some settings in `~/.gemrc`:

```
    - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
    - "gemhome" => "/home4/onezerh4/ruby/gems"
    - "gempath" => []
    - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
```

you need to remove at least the `gemhome` and `gempath` entries from `~/.gemrc`

also note that you do not need to add `--remote` to `gem`

Comment: You may be on to something "gem list' starts off with the output ***REMOTE GEMS***

Comment: Yep, that fixed my problem. 50 reputation well earned :)